# Create a subgraph from multigraph with networkX

Tags: python, networkx

I have a MultiGraph and I want to build a subgraph of all the exiting nodes from an arbitrary starting node.

I've found that for multigraphs not all the functions are available and I'm stuck after loaded the graph with `rdflib`.

My main idea is to extract the connections manually from the list of edges and re-create a graph using only certain nodes, but I'm looking for a more straightforward solution if it exists.

My starting scheme is this:
[image]

I would like to get a subgraph by inserting a starting node like this:
[image]

I built my graph as follows:

```
g = Graph()
graph = g.parse('C:~/name_file.ttl', format='ttl')
grafo =
rdflib.extras.external_graph_libs.rdflib_to_networkx_multidigraph(graph)
```

The edges of my graph are of this type:

````
[(rdflib.term.URIRef('http://~/En_Consum_Rev'), rdflib.term.URIRef('http://~/sum'), rdflib.term.URIRef('http://~/hasAggregationFunction'))]```
````

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code to set up your MultiGraph example? If you can a small schematic of the expected before/after would also make your question more explicit.

Comment: I updated my question with the information you asked for.

Comment: thanks but can you provide a sample of ttl file?